# Azure Application Insight Application map like query

Tags: azure-devops, azure-application-insights, appinsights

I am trying to have the same kind of query as I see in application map but in an exportable format.
I need to have all the dependencies to my main app service grouped by target and then I need to see once each of the queries done in this dependencies.
Something like:

```
My AppService 
 -> Dependency 1
   -> Request 1
   -> Request 2
```

```
dependencies
| summarize by target
```

after that I tried to do a union or something to have the details of the depedencies below but it is the point where I am stuck.

Regards,

Comment: could you pls give a demo of what the result looks like, or in other words, what are the properties you need and which table they are stored... I know it's rude of me but I am a little puzzled on your requirement.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Dependency Tracking in Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies) and [Dependencies in Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#dependencies-in-analytics)